# Flutter how to reload again if internet is restore

Tags: flutter

I have a Carousel widget with own data load using bloc. I have added this widget in home page. If app open, sometime, internet connection is loss and that widget is show blank.

So what I want to do is automatically reload the data if data is not loaded when internet connection restored. May I know how to check and refresh?

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2/persistent-tab-view.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/blocs/bloc.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/connectivity_wrapper/connectivity_wrapper.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/helper/constants.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/helper/enum.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/models/models.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/ui/song/song_screen.dart';
import 'package:thitsarparami/widgets/circular_progress_indicator_widget.dart';

class MonkCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  const MonkCarousel({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MonkCarousel> createState() => _MonkCarouselState();
}

class _MonkCarouselState extends State<MonkCarousel> {
  _loadMonks() async {
    if (await ConnectivityWrapper.instance.isConnected) {
      BlocProvider.of<LatestMonkBloc>(context).add(const GetLastMonksEvent(5));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadMonks();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(
        // minWidth: 160,
        minHeight: 160,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //color: Colors.amberAccent,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            blurRadius: 40,
            offset: const Offset(8, 10),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.18),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: BlocBuilder<LatestMonkBloc, LatestMonkState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LatestMonkError) {
            return Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
            );
          } else if (state is LatestMonkLoaded) {
            return CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                height: 160,
                autoPlay: true,
                autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                autoPlayAnimationDuration: const Duration(
                  milliseconds: 800,
                ),
                viewportFraction: 0.5,
                //enlargeCenterPage: true,
              ),
              items: state.monks.map((monk) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        pushNewScreen(context,
                            screen: SongScreen(
                              monk: monk,
                              album: Album(id: monk.id, monkId: monk.id, title: kLatestDhama),
                              screenMode: SongScreenMode.latest,
                            ),
                            pageTransitionAnimation:
                                PageTransitionAnimation.scale);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            CachedNetworkImage(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 100.0,
                              //fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              imageUrl: monk.imageUrl,
                              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                  Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                  Container(color: Colors.black12),
                              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(
                                Icons.error,
                                size: 100,
                                color: Colors.red,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Flexible(
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                monk.title,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          }
          return const CircularProgressIndicatorWidget();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`connectivity_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package and listen to the network changes.

```dart
subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
    // reload here
  }
});
```

Comment: I put it in initState but not trigger when internet is restore void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _connectivitySubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
          result == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        _loadMonks();
      }
    });
  }